# Nexus staging Maven plugin on a complex Maven project?

Tags: maven, nexus, staging

I am trying to release several maven projects together, by deploying them to oss.sonatype.org, then releasing them to Maven central.

I have a build pom, that I use to build several multi-module projects together. The build pom is not the parent pom, each separate multi-module project has its own parent pom.

In the build pom, I set up the nexus staging plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
      <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
      <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

What happens when I build, is that all the sub-modules are built and uploaded to nexus in a staging repo (say #4005). Then at the end the above plugin opens a new repository (say #4006), uploads just the build pom to it, then closes it. This means that my build pom gets released, but not any of the sub-modules.

Is there some way to explicitly control the life-cycle of this plugin? I want to open new repository at the start of the build, upload all sub modules to it, then close and release it.

Comment: For my understanding, you just can create a aggregator module "pom type" to collect all the sub-modules, then release it, releasing every sub-modules you have...  If they are not built in the same Maven reactor they wont be released togheter, in that case you should release one by one... I'm not talking by a nexus staging maven plugin side, but just from the Maven releasing structure side..

Comment: Thats what I have. The build pom aggregates several other poms, each of which has sub-modules. The overall build pom is not inherited from by the sub modules though, its just to drive the reactor build of them all together.

Comment: Ok got it, please explain me what you wanna do, what you mean with release the modules? you want them to be released and tagged, or just deployed, as for my understanding the staging plugin let you deploy artifacts, but not release them, what if you just run a the release plugin on the aggregator?

Comment: Deployed to a staging repo in oss.sonatype. Then run the checks, and if they pass, release to maven central. This is what the nexus plugin is for; it allows you to script the close/check/release to central part. Sorry, I didn't mention I was trying to release to maven central - I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you build pom is NOT a parent, then the different multi-module projects do NOT have a configuration of the staging plugin either. So are they just being deployed via the deploy plugin? That would be a mixed use case that does not work.

You would have to configure your Maven projects so they all run in one reactor and all deploy with the staging plugin.

The only other option I can think of is to run the full build of all the multi-module children as a normal deployment into one or multiple staging repositories and then subsequently release them together with the [remote control goals](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging-deployment.html) of the staging plugin. That would probably require some scripting or at least some testing how the order of everything works out.

Comment: I shall try adding the staging plugin to each of the multi-module projects and see what happens - perhaps each will end up in its own staging repo? That might not actually be too bad.